# Need your advice after searching a lot about an easy an full PHP system

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications, twitter-bootstrap-3

First i'll say that I have only a minor knowledge about programming in PHP, MySql, Html and js.
Until now I have made some programs with Ms-Access and vba, and some projects on Google App Script with google script...

Now, I have some simple programs I have made with MsAccess but i want to transform them to be Web Based.

I want to build them again from zero, but, like I said before, I dont know really where to start.

I have tried to search on the web, a various of programs or software to help be to build it easily, but i got completely confused.

I have found beautiful responsive Bootstrap themes with the look i'm searching for, but nothing really programmed with I need (connecting to MySql, add rows, pulling data, etc.).

Here are my needs, except the looking:

1. Customers management - Add / update / delete / show / search customers
2. Tickets management - related to customers and again - Add / update / delete / show / search Tickets
3. Web forms
4. Printing or sending by mail pre-filled forms / invoices (like reports in access)
5. An easy Dashboard for all users
6. Users management - Add / update / delete / show / search / configure privileges for Users

Edited question:

Do anyone know of any kind of a full example in php or js where I can copy such code blocks as described above ?

I can mange the rest, I want to start from somewhere...

Thank you for you time.

Comment: I edited it,  hopping its better than before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are wanting customization to this level you will need to invest copious amounts of time and labor into learning PHP and subsequent libraries, such as utilizing PDO for ODBC work. Do note that the details your provided suggest the scope of this project to be quite large.

However, if you're looking for an out-of-the-box solution you may be better suited asking the Software Recommendations community at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/.